# IncompatibleRemoteServiceException while using RPC in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc, gwt2

I have web application Project having RPC call.

one RPC async is working fine. but Another gives a error

```
    Mar 21, 2012 1:34:51 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: ObjectStore: An      IncompatibleRemoteServiceException was thrown while processing this call.
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException: This application is out of date, please click the refresh button on your browser. ( Blocked attempt to access interface 'com.client.RepositoryInterface', which is not implemented by 'com.server.ObjectStore'; this is either misconfiguration or a hack attempt )
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.decodeRequest(RPC.java:252)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:206)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
```

---

Working RPC

```
 public interface ConnectionInterface extends RemoteService{

String connection(String[] authentication);
```

}

```
 public interface ConnectionInterfaceAsync {

void connection(String[] authentication, AsyncCallback<String> callback);
```

}

public class ConnectionService implements ConnectionInterfaceAsync {

```
ConnectionInterfaceAsync service = (ConnectionInterfaceAsync)GWT.create(ConnectionInterface.class);

ServiceDefTarget endpoint = (ServiceDefTarget) service;

public ConnectionService() {

    endpoint.setServiceEntryPoint(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "rpc");
}

public void connectionCMIS(String[] authentication,
        AsyncCallback<String> callbackConnection) {

    service.connectionCMIS(authentication, callbackConnection);

}
```

// client Call

```
public class Login extends Composite  {
 private ConnectionService connectionService = new ConnectionService();
// more code
 public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
      AsyncCallback<String> callbackConnection = new AsyncCallback<String>() {

            public void onSuccess(String result) {
                             // print Succuss
                          }
      }
      connectionService.connection(authentication, callbackConnection );
}
}
```

}

**Not Workink RPC**

```
 public interface RepositoryInterface extends RemoteService {
public FolderCollection getRepositories();
 }

 public interface RepositoryInterfaceAsync {
void getRepositories(AsyncCallback<FolderCollection> repositoryCallback);
 }


  public class RepositoryService implements RepositoryInterfaceAsync{

RepositoryInterfaceAsync async = (RepositoryInterfaceAsync)GWT.create(RepositoryInterface.class);
ServiceDefTarget endpoint = (ServiceDefTarget) async;

public CmisRepositoryService() {
    endpoint.setServiceEntryPoint(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "repository");
}
public void getRepositories(
        AsyncCallback<FolderCollection> repositoryCallback) {

    async.getRepositories(repositoryCallback);
}
}
```

client call

```
 public class Workplace {
  private RepositoryService service = new RepositoryService();
  // some more code
  void doRepo(){
    AsyncCallback<FolderCollection> repositoryCallback = new AsyncCallback<FolderCollection>() {

        public void onSuccess(FolderCollection result) {
        }

        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        }
    };

    service.getRepositories(repositoryCallback);
  }
 }
```

XML Code

```
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>ConnectionServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>com.server.ConnectionServiceImpl</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>ObjectStore</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.server.ObjectStore</servlet-class>
```

```
 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>ConnectionServlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>ObjectStore</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Both RPC is designed in similar patter still it gives me an error.

If any one can tell me why will be of great Help

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL-mapping is off, you need to map your RPC RemoteServiceServlets to a better `url-pattern`. You map both servlets to `/*`. There is no guarantee which Servlet is executed when two or more a mapped to the exact same `url-pattern`. So my guess is, everytime you execute your not working service, the call is mapped to the other service.

A way to work this out would be to use a web.xml like

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ConnectionServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/ConnectionService.rpc</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>ObjectStore</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/ObjectStoreService.rpc</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Of course you also have to change your client-side services to use the correct `serviceEntryPoint` , so

```
 endpoint.setServiceEntryPoint(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "rpc");
```

would have to change to something like

```
 endpoint.setServiceEntryPoint(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "ConnectionService.rpc");
```

to get to the right servlet.

EDIT: Error of change:

**ERROR**

```
 @ftr   `com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: ConnectionServlet: An IncompatibleRemoteServiceException was thrown while processing this call.
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException: This application is out of date, please click the refresh button on your browser. ( Blocked attempt to access interface 'com.client.RepositoryInterface', which is not implemented by 'com.server.ConnectionServiceImpl'; this is either misconfiguration or a hack attempt )
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.decodeRequest(RPC.java:252)
at  com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:206)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
```

So if you look closely, the error is different:

> Blocked attempt to access interface 'com.client.RepositoryInterface', which is not implemented by 'com.server.ConnectionServiceImplObjectStore'

instead of

> Blocked attempt to access interface 'com.client.RepositoryInterface', which is not implemented by 'com.server.ObjectStore'

This means your configuration is still wrong, you have to point your client-side `RepositoryInterfaceAsync` to a `RemoteServiceServlet` that implements `RepositoryInterface`.

Comment: Still I am getting the same error. I am updating the error in Your code.

Comment: @GameBuilder Do you have another service that implements `com.server.ObjectStore`? I just realized that your request to `RepositoryInterface` is actually mapped to that. I still think this is a case of misconfiguration in your web.xml/service entry point.

Comment: No there is only one service whichi s using `com.server.ObjectStore`. But the other service is using `com.server.ConnectionServiceImpl` and `objectStore extends ConnectionServiceImpl`

Comment: @GameBuilder There should be a `RepositoryInterfaceImpl` or something like that providing the server-side implementation of the `RepositoryInterface`-RemoteService. You would also need to declare that in your web.xml and do the appropriate service endpoint definition on the client.

Comment: @GameBuilder your update shows that `ObjectStore` implements Repository-Interface. For this to work, you'd have to adapt the ServiceEndpoint-Definition in your clientside Repository-Service as well - so you'd have to replace ` endpoint.setServiceEntryPoint(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "repository");` with ` endpoint.setServiceEntryPoint(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "ObjectStoreService.rpc");`. This would point your client-side service to the `ObjectStore`-Servlet that you declared in web.xml. This is the service entry point's task - to map your client-service to a server-side servlet.

Comment: `endpoint.setServiceEntryPoint(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "ObjectStoreService.rpc");`   Yes it's  same..

Comment: @GameBuilder another problem I noticed may be the fact that your ObjectStore actually implements two `RemoteService`s because you ObjectStore is a subclass of ConnectionServiceImpl. This might cause the problem, but I'm not sure. Other than that, I don't know anything more I can add.

Comment: there is no problem of subclass. the problem is in mapping servlet.i added `System.out.println("async repo");` above this. ` endpoint.setServiceEntryPoint(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()+ "ObjectStoreService.rpc");` and also after the `RepositoryService`is called. **the output is only `async repo`**  .

Comment: @GameBuilder it would be nice of you to edit your question with your found solution for the next guy that comes across `IncompatibleRemoteServiceException`

Answer (score 0):

It might be misconfiguration of gwt-servlet.jar version on your web-container.Check your development gwt-servlet.jar version and web container gwt-servlet.jar version. n For reference 
[Misconfiguration or hack attempt](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/browse_thread/thread/3239fab80e33701c/)